# Placing value on top of bar chart thematic map using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, thematic-map

Is it possible to place the value on top of each bar in a bar chart thematic map in Mapinfo?

This is how I did it so far: I wanted to show a value per zone (the amount of trips generated in one area) with a bar: the areas which generate more trips have a larger bar. I also wanted to place the value of such bar on top, but as I couldn't find how, I placed the label at the base of the bar by choosing the following label display options:

[image]

This is what the thematic map looks like:

[image: Thematic map - one bar]

I would like the numbers to be on top of the bars, if it is possible, especially because for my next thematic map I will have to represent several fields at a time (origins and destinations, that is: two bars), so I will no longer be able to use labels to show the value.

Comment: Please decide which of MapInfo and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: If I understood correctly, there's somes hints here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/3Y6krURBtLI

Comment: I edited the question to show more detail to what I have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

In the Placement Section of the Label Display Menu change default position from Bottom(B) to Top(T).